# @RequestMapping not working as it's supposed to

Tags: java, spring

I have no issues getting Tomcat to start and automatically display the contents of the index.jsp file. It is however when I try to use a @Controller & @RequestMapping that I am running into an Error. This is my Controller class

```
package fifteenth;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class AddController {

        @RequestMapping("/add")
        public String add() {
            return "display.jsp";
        }

    }
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <display-name>Fifteenth</display-name>
        <servlet-name>fifteenth</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fifteenth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is what i believe to be my dispatcher servlet named fifteenth-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">


    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="fifteenth"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Contents of my index.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="add">
<input type="text" name="t1">
<input type="text" name="t2">
<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So as said before, the index.jsp works fine, but when I click on the button, I get a 404 not found error that "fifteenth/add" is not found.

Comment: Just wondering who forced you to use Spring 2.5 these days? Do not be so hard to yourself ;)

Comment: @ThomasWeglinski I'm following a tutorial online.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet mapping is set up to map `*.htm` URLs.

Try changing the form action to `add.htm` and it should fare better.

Comment: At least I'm now encountering an error I haven't came across. ClassNotFoundException for org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet